# How to run scraper code in a Docker container next to a standalone Selenium container?

Tags: docker, selenium, docker-compose

I am currently re-deploying a simple Python project from my local Windows to an Azure remote host with the help of Docker Compose (I’m totally new to this).

The problem is that some parts (a scraper) of the main logic rely on Selenium and Chrome driver. However, I don’t want to do an extraction and place this **scraper** logic out as I hope the main logic could be set up in a single Celery container.

I am wondering if I could achieve this by integrating a parallel stand-alone Selenium container in the docker-compose.yml file. Like:

```
services:

  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    hostname: chrome

  main_data_tasks:
    build:
      command: 'celery -A task_proj worker'
    links:
      - chrome
    depends_on:
      - chrome
```

If that’s possible, how do I introduce that particular Selenium container’s “context” into the main Celery container where all the code is running? Or this is a dead-end, and I will need to call the Selenium container from the Celery one?

Comment: Can you expand more on what you mean by a "Selenium container's context"? What data do you want to retrieve while it runs? Generally Selenium is run via remote control, so it makes sense to run it as a separate container.

Comment: Calling the Selenium container from the Celery container sounds like an excellent way to do it. It sounds like Celery is a task queue/runner where you have your scraping code - calling Selenium in another container is a good approach. It means that each container can be specialised in what it needs to do, and you don't need monolith containers that do everything.

Comment: Hi halfer, my question is if it's possible to run scraper codes in the main celery image, with some possible configurations to temporarily borrow the selenium env to support these scraper codes. Maybe there is simply no solution like that. For now to get things working I installed chrome/chromedriver through dockerfile in my main celery image. Not so elegant so I am looking for some instructions on how to get a function's return value in containerB from container A. In that case, I can get the result-dict returned by the scraper function to be placed in the selenium container.

Comment: Yes, you would run your scraper code in the Celery image, using a Selenium-aware library. This would point to the IP address of the Selenium container, so it can remote control it.

Comment: Inside your `main_data_tasks` container, you can use the magic DNS reference `chrome` to refer to the address of the Chrome container. This is set up for you by the Docker virtual networking stack.